# using StringTokenizer and searching for a word in text

Tags: java, parsing, text, stringtokenizer

I am using a `StringTokenizer` to tokenize lines of a txt file. I am searching these lines for a specific word - 'son'. How can I prevent the word 'sonnet' from being returned?
See code extracts below:

```
String searchWord = "son";

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text,".?!,^");

if(text.contains(searchWord)){

fw = new FileWriter("txtFiles/tokenizedSentences.txt");

bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(text);
```

Can I enter something into the `StringTokenizer` construct to stop from returning sonnet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

String Tokenizer is a [legacy construct that shouldn't be used](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).  Use [`String.split(regex delimiter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) instead.  To fix your issue you would read text like normal, but if you are only checking for `son`, you need to [check for string equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), not just if the string contains son, so do `Object.equals("son", text)` to find that out.  If you are looking for something more complicated than that, you will need to use [Regular Expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)